# lexical error: malformed number, a digit is required after the minus sign?

Tags: algolia

I am getting the following response when trying to POST an object to an index:

```
{
  "message": "lexical error: malformed number, a digit is required after the minus sign. Around '------WebK' near line:1 column:1", "status": 400
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the request you are sending?

Comment: @Shipow where can I create a ticket with the details?

Comment: support at algolia, someone will help you but we will have to update this thread with the answer.

Comment: @Shipow That's fine. I just sent a ticket.

Answer (score 3):

You need to POST your data as JSON to the API endpoint, not as a `form-data` form submission.

Comment: what if its a file I'm sending?